# Attribute alignment after edit in AutoCAD

Tags: autocad

I have a simple routine that updates the text value of an `attributereference`.  After the routine runs the values are updated in the drawing but the text is left justified and not centered.  I have not been able to find any command that will cause AutoCAD to update the text location.  So any help would be appreciated.

My Code

```
                using (Transaction acTrans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                {
                    BlockTable bt = (BlockTable)acTrans.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);

                    foreach (ObjectId oid in bt)
                    {
                        BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)acTrans.GetObject(oid, OpenMode.ForRead);

                        foreach (ObjectId o in btr)
                        {
                            if (o.ObjectClass.Name == "AcDbBlockReference")
                            {
                                BlockReference br = (BlockReference)acTrans.GetObject(o, OpenMode.ForRead);
                                BlockTableRecord b2 = (BlockTableRecord)acTrans.GetObject(br.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForRead);

                                if (b2.Name == blockName)
                                {
                                    AttributeCollection ac = br.AttributeCollection;

                                    foreach (ObjectId i in ac)
                                    {
                                        AttributeReference ar = (AttributeReference)acTrans.GetObject(i, OpenMode.ForWrite);

                                        string tagName = ar.Tag;

                                        foreach (TestAutoCADCntrl.CBAttributeTag t in tags)
                                        {
                                            if (t.TagName == tagName)
                                            {
                                                ar.Justify = AttachmentPoint.MiddleCenter;
                                                ar.AdjustAlignment(db);
                                                ar.TextString = t.TagValue;
                                                ar.DowngradeOpen();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    br.RecordGraphicsModified(true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    acTrans.Commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I have been searching for this issue for 3 days and found the answer right after i posted this question.  For anyone else you just need to change the working database before you update the attribute text value.

```
foreach (TestAutoCADCntrl.CBAttributeTag t in tags)
{
    if (t.TagName == tagName)
    {
        Database wdb = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;                                                 HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase = db;

        ar.TextString = t.TagValue;
        ar.AdjustAlignment(db);

        HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase = wdb;
    }
}
```

Comment: This suggestion helped me to solve the same issue. But I think you forgot to set the WorkingDatabase to "db" before you call AdjustAlignment. Also you only need to switch WorkingDatabase once and switch back before you commit, not once for each attribute. But thanks! This helped a lot!